# how to get access from an attribute to other objects atributtes

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Im totally new in JS. Could someone help me please? I need to prepare some objects atributes which depends on other objects attributes

How can I achive that?

I tried that solution:

```
var Photo =  {
      current: {
        coordinates: "2208,1922",
        name: "current"
      },
      start: {
        coordinates: '2408,1822',
        name: 'start',
        newCoordinates: Photo.current.coordinates
        }
  };
```

I'm getting an error:

```
module initialization error: TypeError
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var current = {
        coordinates: "2208,1922",
        name: "current"
      }

var Photo =  {
      current: current,
      start: {
        coordinates: '2408,1822',
        name: 'start',
        newCoordinates: current.coordinates
        }
  };
  
  console.log(Photo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wait for the object to be initialized, then you can grab that property.  See this code:

```js
var Photo =  {
      current: {
        coordinates: "2208,1922",
        name: "current"
      },
      start: {
        coordinates: '2408,1822',
        name: 'start'
        }
  };
  
  Photo.start.newCoordinates = Photo.current.coordinates;   // 2208,1922
```